# bootstrap-datepicker : How to change language attribute dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap-datepicker from https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker
and everything works as expected.

My initialization script is

```
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    language: "en"
});
```

But now I want to change the language dynamically and I've tried

```
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    language: $('.active .lang-id').text().toLowerCase() // <- the field from which I read lang param i.e ru, es, etc...
});
```

And it does not work the language is the same as was first read. How to make it work?
Is it even possible?

**UPDATE NO.1**

with a help of @Cameron I succeeded in updating a language dynamically using
this code, but now when I press on a datepicker I can see in a split of a second how the datepicker popup (showing calendar) transitions from a language A to language B. How to avoid this unpleasant effect?

an updated code

```
$('.input-group.date').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).datepicker != null) {
        console.log("is not null");
        $(this).datepicker('destroy');
    }
    currentLanguage = $('.active .lang-id').text().toLowerCase();
    $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        language: currentLanguage
    });
     $(this).datepicker('update');
         $(this).datepicker('show');

    console.log("test" + $('.active .lang-id').text().toLowerCase());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try grabbing the value of the text before the datepicker()

***update,** found some "setDefaults" on jquery Datepicker

```
const language= $('.active .lang-id').text().toLowerCase();
console.log('select language is '+ language);

//be sure your selector is working

$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        language:  language
    });
```

UPDATE

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    const language= $('.active .lang-id').text().toLowerCase();
    //be sure your selector is working
    console.log('select language is '+ language);
    $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            language:  language
        });

});
```

**you may have load the local script**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    const language= $('.active .lang-id').text().toLowerCase();
    //be sure your selector is working
    console.log('select language is '+ language);

const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.${language}.min.js`;

// Append to the `head` element
document.head.appendChild(script);

$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        language:  language
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is still the same static behavior (the language is selected on once after load) other inputs are just ignored. I need to mention that all my scripts are  
placed in my_scripts.js file and this file is loaded at the bottom of body

Comment: can you wrap the datepicker in a doc ready?

Comment: I strongly prefer keeping javascript code snippets in a dedicated js file

Comment: keep it in the dedicated js, just wrap the function in a document ready, so it doesn't try to pull the value of the selector until the whole page has loaded.  See my update above.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So, placing *.js files at the end of </body> tag does not guarantee that the script will be executed after a whole page has been loaded?

Comment: is there other javascript that is setting the language on the .active lang-id?   Does it log the actual text field you are expecting?   (curious) if you manually change the language in the datepicker does that work, just to verify

Comment: No, the field (language) itself changes, but not the datepicker it seems that it needs to be destroyed and recreated on every time the language is changed if I want it to refleact the choice of a new language. See my update no.1

Comment: updated (I found some setDefaults()  maybe that is where the language needs to change )  see my code update above.

Comment: I'm not using jquery Datepicker I'm using bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: is datepicker being called anywhere else?

Comment: No it is not. Only one place.

Comment: what about loading the locale script (i think it defaults to English if one isn't loaded)  so maybe loading the proper locale script will default it to your language.

Comment: after an update no.1 everything seems to work as needed datepicker is changing according to a changed locale, however there is one unpleasant thing when I change the locale and then open datepicker for the first time in a split of a second I can see how datepicker transitions from language A to language B if that could be avoided then it would be perfect