# boostrap-datepicker: How to remove change effect?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Thanks to @Cameron ([bootstrap-datepicker : How to change language attribute dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975189/bootstrap-datepicker-how-to-change-language-attribute-dynamically)) I have a piece of code to change a boostrap-datepicker language

```
$('.input-group.date').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).datepicker != null) {
        console.log("is not null");
        $(this).datepicker('destroy');
    }
    currentLanguage = $('.active .lang-id').text().toLowerCase();
    $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        language: currentLanguage
    });
       $(this).datepicker('show');

    console.log("test" + $('.active .lang-id').text().toLowerCase());
});
```

it works and everything is somehow okay, but upon language change (3rd attempt to open a boostrap-datepicker) I see that nasty transition from English language to other language which I would like to get rid of. How can I do that? What I'm missing?

[image]